# Visual C# Writing to multiple COM ports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, serial-port

I am currently developing an application for output to motor controllers, I can only have 128 of them in one daisy chain and I am running 256 of them. So thus I need to write out 2 serial ports.

My code is basically something like this :

```
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM2";

        if (com1change)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
        }

        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        //serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        if(!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            message = "The Serial Port is not open.";
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }

 //WRITE SOME STUFF OUT THE FIRST PORT


 //change ports here 

 serialPort1.Close();
 serialPort1.PortName = "COM5"
 serialPort1.Open();

//WRITE SOME STUFF OUT THE SECOND PORT`
```

But I am getting errors that are not specific, VS is simply telling me "Access is Denied".

Comment: "VS is simply telling me" - what do you mean, is an exception thrown? If so, where exactly and what is the exception type and precise message?

Comment: Access Denied can be for a number of reasons.  Perhaps "COM5" is not accessible.  I would personally no reuse the same object... you dont know that it cleans up quickly enough or at all to beable to reuse it a few ticks after you closed it.

Comment: Keeping 256 motor controllers going is a much, *much* bigger problem than this one.  You need to go shopping, finding a controller that can handle 16 or 32 motors through one communication channel, and you *really* don't want a serial port, is pretty essential to have any hope.

Comment: Alright, I actually figured it out. I needed to add an entire instance of another serialPort. So I have serialport1 and serialport2, both with different corresponding names, bauds, etc. Simply changing the name will not do this. 



Yes VS threw me an exception throw.

And no, I am going to do it later down the road we are going to do a different setup with relays put in a matrix which give the signals to the correct motors. But for a proof of concept it is this, a driver for each motor, chained into 128 controllers each, hence why I am outputting to 2 serial ports.